# install4j - restrict access to installation folder in Windows

Tags: install4j

We are using install4j v10.0.1.  I'm trying to restrict access to all of the files/folders within the Windows installation directory via use of a "Change Windows file rights" action.  I'm attempting to revoke all access to the installation directory from the "Users" trustee/group, but the Users group still seems to be inheriting "Read & Execute" permissions from a higher-level folder (e.g., C:\Program Files).  I want the Administrators group to have full access to the files/folders within the installation directory, but I don't want the Users group to have any access.  How can I meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Change Windows file rights" action, setting the "Access mode" property to "Revoke access" deletes an existing ACE with the same specification.

In your case, you have to use "Deny access" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I originally tried using "Deny" on the "Users" group, but then nobody could access the installation directory...not even Administrators.  My Administrator user also belongs to the Users group, so I think the Deny is overriding the full access the Administrator group has.

Comment: How about adding another entry to allow access for Administrators?

Comment: I tried that, too.  The deny seems to take precedence, but I'm no expert in Windows permissions.

Comment: I found some information about NTFS permission precedence that might help.  https://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-precedence.htm

Comment: I've tried a few different approaches, but still cannot achieve the result I'm looking for on Windows.  The Users group still ends up with permissions that are inherited from a higher-level folder.  Any other suggestions to try?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea in that regard

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to first use "Change Windows file rights" actions to Set and Revoke privileges to the installation directory as per my requirements.  Then I create a batch script which expects one parameter (the path to the installation directory) and utilizes the "icacls" command available in Windows to remove any privileges the installation directory might inherit from a parent folder.  A "Run executable or batch file" action is used to run the batch script. The contents of the script are as follows:

```
@echo off
set "install_dir=%~1"
icacls "%install_dir%" /inheritancelevel:r
```